# Using a DATE field as primary key of a date dimension with MySQL

Tags: mysql, date, schema, data-warehouse, dimension

I want to handle a date dimension in a MySQL datawarehouse. (I m a  newbie in the DW world)

I made some searches with google and saw a lot of table structures (most of) date dimension where the Primary Key is a simple `UNSIGNED INTEGER`.

Why don't use a `DATE` field as primary key since with MySQL it is 3 Bytes VS 4 Bytes for `INTEGER`?

Ex:

```
CREATE TABLE dimDate
id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY AUTOI_NCREMENT,
date DATE NOT NULL,
dayOfWeek
...
```

VS

```
CREATE TABLE dimDate
date DATE NOT NULL PRIMARY,
dayOfWeek
...
```

Comment: You don't expect to have multiple records for the same date?

Comment: No, i will expect a lot of records for same date in my fact table not the dimension table.

Comment: Kimball says every dimension pk should be a surrogate.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you have a table with a column that is of `date` type and where no two rows will ever have the same date, then you can surely use this column as `PRIMARY KEY`.

You see a lot of examples where the Primary Key is a simple `UNSIGNED INTEGER` because there are many cases where there is no perfect candidate for Primary Key. The `AUTO_INCREMENT` allows this column to be automatically filled by the database (and be unique) during inserts .

Answer (score 24):

**Date dimension** is kind of special -- having date (2011-12-07) or date-related integer (20111207) for a primary key is actually preferred. This allows for nice partitioning (by date) of fact tables.

For other type of dimensions, surrogate (integer) keys are recommended.

As a template, each dimension usually has entries for `unknown, not entered, error, ...` which are often matched with keys `0, -1, -2, ...`

Due to this, it is more common to find integer-formatted date (20111207) as a primary key instead of date -- it is a bit messy to represent  `unknown, not entered, error, ...` with date-type key.