# Should DateKey YYYYMMDD be char(8)?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, data-warehouse

The two most important fields, that are everywhere in our warehouse, are the UserAccountKey and the DateKey.

- DateKey is (int, not null)
- UserAccountKey is (int, not null)

Are these the correct data type?

The WH was created in 2006 so type `Date` wasn't an option, although we are now running `2008-R2` so it is now an option for the next iteration of the WH. It's a well established WH with multiple cubes built from it and a whole reporting system. *Additional* question to the above is when the WH was created would the architect have been better having the DateKey as type `Char(8)` rather than `INT`?

Comment: also see
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8415715/using-a-date-field-as-primary-key-of-a-date-dimension-with-mysql/8416548#8416548

Comment: @DamirSudarevic so maybe it was set up as an integer to make things easy to partition; if it had been type char(8) this wouldn't have been so easy?

Comment: Why would he/she double the key size (in this and all fact tables)? INT = 4 byte; char(8) = 8 byte?  If you often need `'YYYYMMDD'` you can always get it from date dimension, and if it is not there, add it.

Comment: @DamirSudarevic thanks...effectively you are helping answer the question; sounds like size might have been a bit reason for the choice of `int`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's actually a data type especially for dates.  I'd change the `DateKey` type from `int` to [`date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352).

Comment: +1:  by making it a `date`, it enables all kinds of date-related functionality, like *DateKey + 1 week* which is written [`dateadd(week, 1, DateKey)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx).

Comment: ok - so this is one of the new data types? and even though it looks like 20120622 it can have a type date? when WH was set up I wonder why he used int?!

Comment: `date` was introduced in SQL Server 2008, so it might not have been around when the WH was created.

Comment: yep ; the WH was created in 2006 so type `Date` wasn't an option. It's a well established WH with multiple cubes built from it and a whole reporting system. I'll add these details to the OP.

Comment: In a warehouse environment often dates are integers for ease of joining to the Calendar table, which has the actual *date* type in there. Often, I include both the integer YYYYMMDD as well as a date / datetime datatype in the fact table, so I can both do date arithemetic as well as filter based on "business" dates, like workdays, holidays, etc, with an easy join to the other dimension.