# Distinct Count Via SQLFiddle

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlfiddle

This seems weird: [[SQL FIDDLE]](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b4130/3)

The two users are definitely different i.e 1<>2. So why is the distinct count saying 1 ?

Comment: @Lamak...nice one; thought I was going mad!

Comment: Additionally, I don't know if this is an academic exercise, but I'd definitely focus on using appropriate data types (datetime).

Comment: @swasheck ?! not academic, wish life was, we've got a 1000GB warehouse that uses `DateKey INT`... it saves space using that type for that key

Comment: @whytheq Do you think INT requires less storage than DATE?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Typically by convention all the dimension IDs are ints.  Whether they are anonymous or "smart" depends http://www.kimballgroup.com/html/designtipsPDF/DesignTips2006/KU85SmartDateKeysPartitionFactTables.pdf  Prior to 2008, I would have agreed to use them instead of DATETIME.  Now we have DATE, which is preferable.

Comment: @CadeRoux I'm curious why `INT` was preferred over `SMALLDATETIME`, even before SQL Server 2008. Same storage size but still allows for all of the date/time operations, automatic validation, etc. With an `INT` key you can shove `20120230` in there unless you have complex constraints or triggers - and you haven't gained anything over `2012-02-28` in a `SMALLDATETIME` column!

Comment: @AaronBertrand my mistake Aaron; getting my Types mixed up... it was this recent [question of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170677/should-datekey-yyyymmdd-be-char8) where I'd asked why we had used `INT` rather than `CHAR(8)` for the DateKey  - the answer being size. But as you've pointed out my actual question _should_ have been "Why use `INT` when we could have used `SMALLDATETIME`?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use `distinct [User]`

User is a special word

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b4130/20

Answer (score 3):

`user` is a reserved keyword.  If you run:

```
select DateKey, User from the_table
```

you'll see that user is not `1` or `2`, but something like `user_b1234`.  Like Lamak suggested, use `[user]` to refer to the column and not the system variable.

Comment: I guess `date` is a less reserved keyword, but I'd still enclose it in `[]` :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's an answer with some explanation...

User is not only a reserved word. It's more like a system defined read-only global variable.

- It evaluates to the name of the current database user. So every row will get the same value and count(distinct user) is 1.
- User produces the same value as the system defined USER_NAME() function.

So if you want User to be treated as a column name, write [User] as others have suggested, and as you did in your create table statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
select 
    COUNT(DateKey)
    ,count(distinct User) Cnt
from the_table
where Datekey = 20120103
group by 
    DateKey
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b4130/14/0